# Django accepting GET parameters

Tags: django, url, parameters

Error can be seen here: http://djaffry.selfip.com:8080/

I want the index page to accept parameters, whether it be

```
mysite.com/search/param_here
```

or

```
mysite.com/?search=param_here
```

I have this in my URL patterns, but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^$/(?P<tag>\w+)', 'twingle.search.views.index'),
    )
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all your regular expression in url pattern is wrong.

```
r'^$/(?P<tag>\w+)'
```

It says to match everything from

- ^ the beginning of line
- $ to the end of line
- having pattern named tag which is composed of words and digits **after the line end**

Usually after the one line ends comes another line or EOF not content (unless you use multiline regexp and you don't need those here).

Line end should be after the tag:

```
r'^/(?P<tag>\w+)$'
```

---

**Using a query string**

[Query strings are not parsed by url reslover.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against)

Thus, if you have url in format:

```
http://mysite.com/?query=param_here
```

will match:

```
(r'^$', 'twingle.search.views.index')
```

In this case you can access `query` string in view like so:

```
request.GET.get('query', '')
```

**Without a query string**

```
mysite.com/search/param_here
```

will match:

```
(r'^search/(?P<query>\w+)$', 'twingle.search.views.index'),
```

Where everything that matches `\w` (you should change this to suite your needs) will be passed along with request to index view function as argument named `query`.

**Both**

You can use both url patterns like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('twingle.search.views',
   url(r'^$', 'index'),
   url(r'^search/(?P<query>\w+)$', 'index'),
)
```

In this example the view would look something like this:

```
def index(request, query=None)
    if not query:
       query = request.GET.get('query', '')
    # do stuff with `query` string
```

Comment: I am getting an error using `url(r'^search/(?P<param>\w+)$', 'index')`, invalid syntax (urls.py, line 9)

any idea why?

Comment: If you copy/pasted my last urlpatterns example code with both patterns, it seems i forgot a comma after the first url pattern. I've fixed ti now.

Comment: I've also edited urlpatterns (renamed `<param>` to `<query>`) to be easier to use in view and added a view example.