# Sending multiple parameters in url as GET request in django?

Tags: django

I am sending a GET request from jquery as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewspecs/itemdetails?param1="+variable1+"&param2="+ variable2
```

The urls.py file in django for this section looks something like:

```
url(r'^viewspecs/itemdetails?param1=(?P<specs_search_item>[\w\+%_ ./-]+)&param2=(?P<item_price>[0-9])$', views.specsView),
```

When I access the address ,I get a page not(404) error. why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django accepting GET parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891441/django-accepting-get-parameters)

Comment: why not define url like this `viewspecs/itemdetails` and access using `viewspecs/itemdetails?param=search_item`

Comment: In the same way how would you accomplish this for two parameters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your url should be,

```
url(r'^viewspecs/itemdetails/$', views.specsView),
```

And view will be like,

```
def specsView(request):
    param1 = request.GET['param1']
    param2 = request.GET['param2']
```

And if you want to pass parameters as,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewspecs/itemdetails/param1/param2
```

then urls will be,

```
url(r'^viewspecs/itemdetails/(?P<param1>[\w-]+)/(?P<param2>[\w-]+)/$', views.specsView),
```

view will be like this,

```
def specsView(request, param1, param2):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks man! This solved my problem. Learned something new today. By the way I found the first method easier .

Answer (score 0):

If You are going to use this method

```
def specsView(request):
    param1 = request.GET['param1']
    param2 = request.GET['param2']
```

use .get() function

```
def specsView(request):
    param1 = request.GET.get('param1')
    param2 = request.GET.get('param2')
```

as this will not throw any errors even if the parameters are missing
(or optional)